# What to do if you answer a question correctly?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

I've answered a couple of questions correctly but they are yet to turn green. Am I supposed to notify the moderators or do not. I'm not sure.

Comment: The person who asked the question has to select your answer as the correct one - only one answer can be correct, and not all questioners return or bother to select the correct answer. Mods can't select an answer, only the OP.

Comment: On the side-note remember to explain your ID question answers, that's how it will get more appreciation from community.

Comment: Hi Darren. You're not supposed to notify the Mods, but what you *can* do (if the OP actually commented that the answer is correct but forgot to accept it) is to *remind* the OP, via a comment along the lines of: "@OP'sName Don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the check mark next to it". Some of the OPs are new to the site and aren't aware of this function.

Answer (score 7):

As James correctly says in his comment, the person who asks the question is the only person who can select the correct answer.  This is particularly a problem with ID questions for which a lot of people join the site to ask one question and don't stay long enough to learn the etiquette of the site.

Your contribution to the site is however very welcome!

For more information on 'accepting answers' you can view the relevant [help pages](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: ...and no, please do *not* notify the moderators about unaccepted answers. They neither can, nor should, nor want to do anything about it.